# Using r: bind rows of multiple dataframes, which may or may not exist

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm running a script that creates multiple dataframes, with some columns the same and some different, and uses bind_rows to combine them. There are situations where some of the dataframes will not be created (at least one will always be created).

So something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                  age = c(23, 41, 32)
)
df2 <- NULL
df3 <- NULL
df4 <- data.frame(name = c("Joe", "Tim", "Lisa"),
                  gender = c('m', 'm', 'f')
)

all <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

The issue, of course, is that bind_rows won't accept null values. So how can I get around that?

There are a maximum of five dataframes to be created. So maybe a loop to check for the existence of each dataframe, then add those that exist to a list, and bind rows of the dataframes in that list? I'm not sure what a good strategy is here. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I botched the set-up here. The issue was handling a dataframe in a bind_rows function that did not exist at all. So like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                  age = c(23, 41, 32)
)
df2 <- NULL

all <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

Reading the solutions here and realizing that a null df wouldn't be an issue gave me the idea to add a if-else statement that created a null df if the df didn't exist and that solved the issue.

Comment: What do you get for `all <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4)` ?  This runs without any error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bind_rows` is working with `NULL` values (tested on `packageVersion('dplyr')# 1.0.4`

```
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4)
   name age gender
1   Jon  23   <NA>
2  Bill  41   <NA>
3 Maria  32   <NA>
4   Joe  NA      m
5   Tim  NA      m
6  Lisa  NA      f
```

Comment: You're right and thanks. I screwed up the set-up for my issue, but your response still got me to a solution.